# When you zip a project in Android Studio, does the apk file also get included?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I noticed that on the left side of Android Studio(Beta) 0.8.0, there wasn't a .apk file listed. I already zipped the entire directory where my project is, but I'm just wondering, did the apk file also get zipped? Thanks!

EDIT: I've done "Build", then "Make Project" as suggested by the answer below. But I still can't find the apk file! Here's what I see on my screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the apk ends up in `<project>\<module>\build\outputs\apk`. So it should've been included.

**If** you actually built it, of course!

Comment: Oh, thanks for the answer! Sorry I'm new to Android, but how would I build the apk??

Comment: @Karen Build -> Make Project

Comment: Oh cool! Thanks! Would it be under: build -> intermediates? I see something in there named, "model_data.bin". Because I thought the file would end in ".apk". :/

Comment: @Karen no, there is another build directory, under a directory with the module name (such as "app") or whatever you used

Comment: Hmm, I don't see any .apk file in there, let me put up a screenshot of what I see.

Comment: @Karen Those folders are not shown inside Android Studio itself. Use the OS file explorer to check them.